# Django variables to HTML strings

Tags: html, django, variables, object

So I have passed in strings with Django to my HTML template.

```
def media(request, media_id):
    specificMedia = get_object_or_404(Stream, pk=media_id)
    channel = str(specificMedia.channel)
    urldata = "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + str(channel)
    urlvalue = "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=" + str(channel) + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25"

    return render(request, 'livestream/media.html', {'specificMedia': specificMedia, 'channel': channel, 'urldata': str(urldata), 'urlvalue': str(urlvalue)})
```

now I want to use these in my html

```
<p>URLDATA: {{urldata}}</p>
<p>URLVALUE: {{urlvalue}}</p>

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    height="378" 
    width="620" 
    id="live_embed_player_flash" 
    data= {{urlvalue}}
    bgcolor="#000000">
  <param  name="allowFullScreen" 
      value="true" />
  <param  name="allowScriptAccess" 
      value="always" />
  <param  name="allowNetworking" 
      value="all" />
  <param  name="movie" 
      value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
  <param  name="flashvars" 
      value= {{urlvalue}}
</object>
```

So the first ones worked perfectly and printed out my URLs, but the ones in the object seem to not be working. I'm not sure how to test them, but the livestreams that I am trying to display are not showing up. They are supposed to be in the form of a string on the html code. How do I make the variables strings in HTML?

Thanks

Comment: What's the content of the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "making them strings".  If you're serialising a template into HTML, everything ends up as a string.

The mistake I can see is that you've left out the quotes for the attribute value and forgotten to close the tag/element.  Change this:

```
<param name="flashvars" value= {{urlvalue}}
```

...to this:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="{{urlvalue}}" />
```